# How can I recursively remove sharing for a user in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, sharing, permissions, file-sharing

How do I recursively remove permissions for a user in Google Drive? I don't have an apps administrator. I can find all the files shared with the person with `to:email@example.com`. I can't edit each file manually. There are thousands. I can't scroll and select all files either, because the web page locks up. I do share the folder and unshare it, but it shares recursively and doesn't unshare recursively. The shares are sticky to the files.

Similar to this question, but for personal Google Drive, not a company Drive account: [Is it possible recursively remove permissions / sharing from a single user in Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87853/is-it-possible-recursively-remove-permissions-sharing-from-a-single-user-in-go)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not possible. Google does not have the tools for and refer to 3rd party scripts. They confirmed to me that they do not offer this much needed admin functionality to better manage permissions. In our case our Google Drive has become unmanageable now.

Comment: To which 3rd party scripts does Google refer?